# Web3.js 1.0 sendSignedTransaction returns error: Invalid RLP

Tags: web3js, transactions, parity, raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

Running parity private PoA chain, using latest parity client + nodejs + web3.js 1.0

When I try to sign a transaction and then send it following web3.js 1.0 documentation ([sendTransaction](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) and [sendSignedTransaction](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction)) I get the following error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: Invalid RLP.
>       at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/simoh/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
>       at /home/simoh/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:137:36
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/simoh/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:64:13)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/simoh/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/simoh/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/simoh/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/simoh/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
>       at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

This is my code:

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
  nonce: 11377,
  gasPrice: '0x00',
  gasLimit: '0x2DC6C0',
  to: '0x00d4dc44dfbbcb7d8369ddcd261bdaad1872d652',
  from: account.address,
  value: '0x16345785D8A0000',
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}, account.privateKey)
.then(function(result) {
  console.log("Results: ", result)

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(result.rawTransaction)
    .on('receipt', console.log);
})
```

The account is defined in the following way:

```
var account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

In addition it is not very clear to me why as example for [sendSignedTransaction](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction), it is shown a method that uses 'ethereumjs-tx' which is different than the one proposed in the documentation. Using this second method with 'ethereumjs-tx' the same transaction as the code above is succesfully signed and sent.

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

var privateKey = new Buffer('private key', 'hex');

    var rawTx = {
          nonce: 11376,
          gasPrice: '0x00',
          gasLimit: '0x2DC6C0',
          to: '0x00d4dc44dfbbcb7d8369ddcd261bdaad1872d652',
          from: '0x0013a861865d784d97c57e70814b13ba94713d4e',
          value: '0x16345785D8A0000',
          data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
        }

    var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(privateKey);
    var myString = "0x"
    var serializedTx = (tx.serialize()).toString('hex');
    myString += serializedTx
    console.log(myString);

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(myString)
    .on('receipt', console.log);
```

Also when I use `web3.eth.accounts.recoverTransaction(result.rawTransaction‌​)` 
it is showing different public key than what's expected...

Comment: I'm interested in the answer for this as well as how to get the data for the [signTransaction](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) call. In the earlier web3.js 0.x versions, there was getData methods on web3.eth.contract.new and web3.eth.contract.myMethod. getData has been dropped in web3 version 1.0

Answer (score 3):

```
let send_add = send_public_address;

let recv_add = rec_public_address;

let transfer_amount = web3.toWei(data.amount, 'ether');

let nonce = web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(send_public_address));

var private_key = privatekey_sender.slice(2);

let gas = web3.toHex(data.gas_limit);

let gasPrice = web3.toHex(data.gas_price);

var rawTx = {

        from: send_add,

        nonce: nonce,

        gasLimit: gas,

        gasPrice: gasPrice,

        value: web3.toHex(transfer_amount),

        to: recv_add,

    };

var transaction = new tx(rawTx);

var txData = new Buffer(private_key, 'hex');

transaction.sign(txData);

var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, function (err, txHash) {

  if (txHash) {

            next(null, txHash);

        }

        else if (err && err.message) {

            next(err.message, null);

        }

        else {

            next('Unable to sendRawTransaction', null);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Your code uses web3 v0.20.x and the question is about web3 v1.0

Comment: @puneet please add some explanation to your answer...